# Php strrpos detects no string, always 0 position

Tags: php, string, foreach, strpos

Hi guys this is really stunning questions.

I have many experience with strrpos but this is really out of sense . First the array:

```
arrCopy => {                
  ["Codice"]=>                
  string(33) "Per sport d Ã¨ numerico"                
  ["Maniche"]=>                
  string(15) " maniche corte "                
  ...               
  ["Taglia"]=>                
  string(8) "tg tg XL"                
}
```

I want to isolate behaviour of "Taglia" in a Foreach loop, but I cannot detect it!

```
foreach ($arrCopy as $key=>$spec){
         echo gettype($key); // prints string
         $tg= strpos(strtolower($key) , 'taglia'); // gives me 
//always 0 also with "Taglia" key
            if (  $tg !== false || ....
                 // never goes there
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should test the retval of strpos() against FALSE, to determine whether the string is contained.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Probably better to use strcmp - you're not so much trying to find a substring, as to ensure a match.

Comment: I used the operator like you said please check I have wrote
    if (  $tg !== false

Problem was found anyway I was wrong with the if statement, sorry to bother